# Error installing PSDK for MK3100

Tags: visual-studio-2008, motorola

Downloaded file PSDK from [this link](https://atgsupportcentral.motorolasolutions.com/ewa/pub/getFile.do?fileName=/ssi/emb/downloads/PSDKMK31x0c70V1.00.0002.exe)

There's an error when installing this, "Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 is necessary for this install. Setup will now exit."

But I have already Visual Studio 2008 installed. I already tried searching but could not find an answer. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem, I actually solved this by extracting the installer from the msi.

Here are the steps I did:

Try to install the psdk (PSDKMK31x0c70V1.00.0002.exe), if it goes on without error then there's no problem, but if it says  "Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 is necessary for this install. Setup will now exit." and you're pretty sure you have vs2008 installed, do not close the error.

Instead go to your Temp folder (run %temp%), there will be 2 folders there that was created by the installer, you can easily find it because folder name is composed of numbers (mine is "{655DE2BF-C2D0-4DA2-B0A8-A05C44724476}").

One of those folder will contain a file called "Windows CE Platform SDK V1.0  for MK3100c70 and MK3190c70.msi".

There's actually another msi inside that msi. I used 7zip to extract that (mk3100c70psdk_os35_25.msi), tried to install it and worked.

Answer (score 0):

This installation program of "**Windows CE Platform SDK** V1.0 for **Motorola** MK3100c70 and MK3190c70" seems buggy, I can't install that I have **Microsoft Visual Studio 2008** Professional Edition (version 9.0.30729.1 SP) installed.